# destroying and creating session in the same function

Tags: php, codeigniter

in my logout function i like to destroy all session except one 
here is my function :

```
    public function out(){

    $ref = $this->session->userdata('ref'); 
    var_dump($ref);

    $this->session->sess_destroy();

    $this->session->set_userdata('ref', $ref ); 


    $ref = $this->session->userdata('ref'); 
    echo '---------------------------------------<br />';
    var_dump($ref);


    }
```

but this doesnt work and it destroys all the session even `ref` and when i check `ref` in the next page i get `null`

inn the function page i get this output :

```
array (size=2)
  'val' => int 666
  'date' => int 1397060477

---------------------------------------

array (size=2)
  'val' => int 666
  'date' => int 1397060477

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: last_activity

Filename: drivers/Session_cookie.php

Line Number: 590

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: session_id

Filename: drivers/Session_cookie.php

Line Number: 611

Backtrace:
```

**im using 3.0-dev**

Comment: You can't write to a session after destroying it.  You'd need to create a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function out(){

    $ref = $this->session->userdata('ref'); 
    $this->session->sess_destroy(); // this kills the ID/cookie

    $this->session->sess_create(); // properly start a new session with new ID/cookie

    if($ref)        
    $this->session->set_userdata('ref', $ref ); 

     redirect(base_url().'index');  

}
```

**Note:**

`sess_create()` is not documented here: [CodeIgniter Sessions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

You have to look at `/system/libraries/Session.php` to find `sess_create()`

**UPDATE**

When using Dev 3.0 then you need to do this:

```
$this->session->__construct();
```

Comment: thanx , i've added more info .... btw i get `Call to undefined method CI_Session::sess_create() `

Comment: I use CI 2.1.4 so you need to go hunting in that file I referenced.

Comment: Holy balls it's way different now: **[CI 3.0 Session.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/release/3.0/system/libraries/Session/Session.php)**. Try `$this->session->__construct();` instead of `sess_create()`

Comment: **[~2800 commits since 2.1.1](http://lonnieezell.com/whats-new-in-codeigniter-3/)**

Comment: thanx , i've solve it by loading sess libe again after destroying it but this works too

Comment: I'd have to look at the source code deeper but I am 95% sure that loading the library again is wasting resources. So definitely use `__construct()` =)

Comment: yeah i used `construct` instead

Answer (score 0):

thanx guys , i've solved it by loading session libe manully in the function after destroyin it ... even though i'm auto loading sess lib !

i guess they never going to solve sess lib problems !

```
public function out(){

$ref = $this->session->userdata('ref'); 
$this->session->sess_destroy();

$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata('ref', $ref ); 

 redirect(base_url().'index');  

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Session is destroyed yet not recreated after destruction. Perhaps your session class should have a session_start in the constructor

Answer (score -1):

After you destroy a session, I believe it would be this line:

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

You have no session at all, so you can't put anything to it.

You first store session variables in variable $ref, then you destroy whole session, and again trying to put something in session. So after destroy, you have to start another session. Something like this:

```
public function out(){

$ref = $this->session->userdata('ref'); 
$this->session->sess_destroy();
session_start(); // put ur session_start func here
if($ref)        
$this->session->set_userdata('ref', $ref ); 

 redirect(base_url().'index');  

}
```